# How to reduce jQuery code

Tags: jquery

In this, I try to open a dialog click on the button.

It's working well but I want to reduce this code because it looks like same on click function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog_form_file").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Help",
    width: 450,
    buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  $("#dialog_form").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Help",
    width: 450,
    buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  $("#dialog_help").click(function() {
    $("#dialog_form_file").dialog('open');
  });
  $("#change_button").click(function() {
    $("#dialog_form").dialog('open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="dialog_form_file" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog_form" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The .dialog function of jquery ui should have a html parameter. Read the doc.

Comment: 1. I added jQuery UI to your code - it was not a [mcve] 2. you are hiding everything. Please update the snippet to work - add the link and button

Comment: @user5014677 You mean [this doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) where it states that the `dialog()` method has no `html` parameter? The OPs use of `dialog()` is absolutely fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/aspoptua/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog_form_file, #dialog_form").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Help",
    width: 450,
    buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  
  $("#dialog_help, #change_button").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data('modal')).dialog('open');
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="dialog_form_file" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog_form" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="dialog_help" data-modal="dialog_form_file">
Submit 1
</button>
<button type="submit" id="change_button" data-modal="dialog_form">
Submit 1
</button>
```

Additional code in `HTML`

```
<button type="submit" id="dialog_help" data-modal="dialog_form_file"> Submit 1</button>
<button type="submit" id="change_button" data-modal="dialog_form"> Submit 1</button>
```

Change of code in `JavaScript`

```
$("#dialog_help, #change_button").click(function() {
   $("#" + $(this).data('modal')).dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your code by doing:

`$("#dialog_form_file, #dialog_form").dialog({`

You don't need to write same code again for 2 difference selectors.

Comment: i try to do this but both dialog open same place
$("#dialog_help, #change_button").click(function(){
  $("#dialog_form_file #dialog_form").dialog('open');
 });